# Find the Cordova directory on MacOs

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a MacBook where Cordova is installed, but I don't know where.
There is a simple way to find the directory where Cordova is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which cordova` to show you where the cordova binary is located.

In my installation, it nets this:

```
$ which cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova
```